# get the next id if last one deleted

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

i have bill and product_bill tables.

i need to use bill_id in product_bill table and i should create bill first ,
so id did this

```
public function store(Request $request)
{

    if( Bill::first() == null )
    {
        $bill_id = 1;
    }
    else {

        $bill_id = Bill::orderBy('id','desc')->first()->id +1 ;
    }
    // dd($bill_id);
    $brand_id = auth('brand')->id();
    $bill = new Bill();
    $bill->brand_id = $brand_id;
    $bill->date = Carbon::today();

    $data = $request->all();
    $products = [];
    $total = 0;
    for($i = 0 ; $i<count($data['id']) ; $i++)
    {   
        $prod = new ProductsBill();
        $prod->product_id = $data['id'][$i] ;
        $prod->quantity = $data['quantity'][$i];
        $prod->bill_id = $bill_id;
        $products[] = $prod->attributesToArray();
        $price = Product::find($prod->product_id)->price;
        $total += $price * $prod->quantity;
    }
    $bill->total = $total;
    $bill->save();
    ProductsBill::insert($products);

    return redirect()->back();

}
```

when i delete any bill the new bill_id in product_bill table get the next number for last one,
i need to know the id will be create next
thanks.

Comment: you need get prev ID of bill and set that id on your product and then delete bill.

Comment: it's great idea , but how i can make this global ?

Comment: write any service where input will be bill which want to delete. If you delete bill call serviceBill->delete(bill) and inside recalculate ids for all products

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use `save()` function on your `$bill` variable, you will get the id by accessing `$bill->id`. If you want to ensure that you transaction is completed, you could use [DB transactions](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/database#database-transactions).

```php
use DB;

class ... {

   ...

    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $brand_id = auth('brand')->id();
        $bill = new Bill();
        $bill->brand_id = $brand_id;
        $bill->date = Carbon::today();

        DB::beginTransaction();

        try{
            $bill->save();

            $data = $request->all();
            $products = [];
            $total = 0;
            for($i = 0 ; $i<count($data['id']) ; $i++)
            {   
                $prod = new ProductsBill();
                $prod->product_id = $data['id'][$i] ;
                $prod->quantity = $data['quantity'][$i];
                $prod->bill_id = $bill->id;
                $products[] = $prod->attributesToArray();
                $price = Product::find($prod->product_id)->price;
                $total += $price * $prod->quantity;
            }
            $bill->total = $total;
            $bill->save();
            ProductsBill::insert($products);

            DB::commit();

            return redirect()->back();

        } catch(\Illuminate\Database\QueryException $ex){ 
            DB::rollBack();
            // Exception redirect here

        }
    }

    ...

}
```

Comment: If `total` is required in your `Bill` model, you can initialize equals to 0 at first save().

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your issue correctly, you could probably use the mysql functions to get the last inserted ID and add one to that.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id

Comment: this wont work because it get the last inserted id , i need that will come next .
because if the last id deleted and it was 10 and i used that it will gave me 9 as the last one